# Ruby function titled inflect

Tags: ruby

Here is ruby code:

```
[:val1, :val2, :val3].each do |method_name|
  define_method(met_n) do |param1, param2|
    inflect(param1, param2, SOME_CONST[met_n.to_s])
  end
end
```

It's not mine code. I tried to figure out what `inflect` is, but I failed, although it should be a standard ruby function.

So how is it defined or where do I find a documentation about it?

Comment: Where did you find the code? [Active Support](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-inflections) is able to do inflections, and the examples use `inflect` for the block parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`inflect` isn't a standard ruby function. This must be part of someone else's API.